# How to set data from all upper or all lower case to a camel case and proper case?

Tags: apex

I'd like to know is there a formula or some other feasible way in Salesforce to set Camel case?

I have data entered into the fields of all upper or all lower case. I need "SALESFORCE FORMULA" , to be dispalyed like "Salesforce Formula".

Please advise how this can be achieved in Salesforce?

Comment: Best you provide an example of the starting string: if there are no delimiters (underscores, spaces etc) then short of using a very large dictionary of words finding the boundaries will not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the criteria to convert to title case is only space between words and you are fine with use of Apex. Below is the apex code which does it, which I found over [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008ukJIAQ). This also eliminates the words like 'of', 'for', 'and', etc. from converting to the title case.

```
//converts a given string to Title Case where the
//first letter of every word is capitalised and the rest are small
public String toTitleCase(String phrase){
  String titlePhrase = '';
  //a set of words that should always (or at least, almost always) be in lower case when in Title Case
  //eg The Day of the Jackal.  First and last word of a phrase should always be Capped though.
  Set<String> forceLower = new Set<String>{'of', 'the', 'for', 'and', 'a', 'to', 'at' ,'an', 'but', 'if', 'or', 'nor'};

  if(phrase != null && phrase.length() > 0){
    String[] splitPhrase = phrase.trim().split(' ');

    for(integer i = 0; i < splitPhrase.size(); i++){
      if(!forceLower.contains(splitPhrase[i].toLowerCase()) || i == 0 || i == (splitPhrase.size()-1) ){
        titlePhrase += (splitPhrase[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase())+(splitPhrase[i].substring(1).toLowerCase())+' ';
      }else{
        titlePhrase += splitPhrase[i].toLowerCase()+' ';
      }
    }
  }
    return titlePhrase.trim();
  }
```

See if this helps!